# Commutation of Lindblad operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-optics

Let operator $\mathcal{L}_{AD}(\rho)$ and $\mathcal{L}_{PD}(\rho)$ is defined as

$$\mathcal{L}_{AD}(\rho)=2a\rho{a}^{\dagger}-a^{\dagger}a\rho-\rho{a^{\dagger}}a$$

and $$\mathcal{L}_{PD}(\rho)=2a^{\dagger}a\rho{a^{\dagger}}a-(a^{\dagger}a)^2\rho-\rho(a^{\dagger}a)^2$$

where '$a$' and '$a^{\dagger}$' are single mode bosonic ladder operators and '$\rho$' is the density operator

As we could see it is easy to show that $\mathcal{L}_{AD}(\rho)$ and $\mathcal{L}_{PD}(\rho)$ commute with each other.
i.e, $$[\mathcal{L}_{AD}(\rho),\mathcal{L}_{PD}(\rho)]=0$$

But if I do explicit calculation to show they commute with each other, I get this expression
$$[a\rho{a^{\dagger}},a^{\dagger}a\rho{a^{\dagger}}a]-2[a^{\dagger}{a}\rho,a^{\dagger}a{\rho}{a^{\dagger}}a] - 2[{\rho}a^{\dagger}a , a^{\dagger}a{\rho}{a^{\dagger}}a]-2[a{\rho}a^{\dagger} , (a^{\dagger}a)^2{\rho}] + [a^{\dagger}a{\rho} , (a^{\dagger}a)^2{\rho}]+[{\rho}{a}^{\dagger}a , (a^{\dagger}a)^2{\rho}]-2[a{\rho}a^{\dagger} , {\rho}(a^{\dagger}a)^{2}]+ [a^{\dagger}a{\rho},{\rho}(a^{\dagger}a)^{2}] +[\rho{a^{\dagger}}a , {\rho}(a^{\dagger}a)^{2}]    $$

But from here I don't know how to proceed to show the commutator vanishes.

Comment: Hint: ${\mathcal L}_{AD}$ and ${\mathcal L}_{PD}$ commute as _superoperators_ applied onto $\rho$, that is, $[{\mathcal L}_{AD},\;{\mathcal L}_{AD}] (\rho) = 0$, not  $[{\mathcal L}_{AD}(\rho),\;{\mathcal L}_{AD}(\rho)] = 0$.

Comment: Oh thanks. But If they commute as superoperators applied onto $\rho$, can we able to write it  as $\mathcal{L}_{AD}(\mathcal{L}_{PD})=\mathcal{L}_{PD}(\mathcal{L}_{AD})$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means :)

Comment: @Muthumanimaran What Noiralef said.

Comment: @udrv How so that $\mathcal{L}_{AD}$ and $\mathcal{L}_{PD}$ commute? The superoperator $\mathcal{L}_{AD}$ is not Hermitian, so I don't think that it cummutes with $\mathcal{L}_{PD}$.

Comment: ${\mathcal L}_{AD}$ may not be Hermitian, but it does commute with ${\mathcal L}_{PD}$: $${\mathcal L}_{AD}\left({\mathcal L}_{PD}(\rho) \right) - {\mathcal L}_{PD}\left({\mathcal L}_{AD}(\rho) \right) = 0 $$